# The flexslider is not product pictures in WooCommerce with Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, flexslider

Can you help I currently manage this website https://ecolamp.co.uk/ with Woocommerce products and Avada child theme installed. We have added https SSL and all is fine except products are no missing on single page listings

display none ref: https://ecolamp.co.uk/product/used-pallet-box-weee-waste/ .

Tried to fix for over an hour and unable to rectify. Any ideas on how we can fix this issue. Also i;ve noticed with the flexslider on the products that have more than 1 x image on the single product page they show fine. But are now very large and blurrred it does not make sense see this page:

https://ecolamp.co.uk/product/new-solid-rigid-pallet-box/

cheers Paul

Answer (score 1):

Go to  **WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display > Product Images.**

You can either choose hard crops or upload the same size image to avoid blurred images.

reference: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/fixing-blurry-product-images